# Problems with Opera and TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, opera

I have been having some general problems with [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) inside Opera. Some of these include:

- the save button produces an error
- when submitting to a popup with an entire form, including TinyMCE, nothing gets posted to the popup (when TinyMCE is removed it works fine)

Has anyone else experienced these errors and/or does anyone have a solution to make TinyMCE more compatible with Opera?

Comment: I use Opera as my primary browser, and I always try to disable WYSIWYG editors.  Not only does the DHTML tend not to be compatible, Opera has for years been using the keyboard for its own operations and functions.

Comment: This is for a site I'm developing where they need the WYSIWYG and I'd like it work in Opera so I don't have to worry about switching to another browser all the time as Opera is also my primary browser.

Comment: Darryl Hein, you should check Opera's error console to copy and paste the errors, specifically the JavaScript errors (assuming there are any).

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE is not the only rich text editor for web. You could even try a [what you mean editor](http://www.wymeditor.org) or some Flash based solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [CKEditor](http://www.ckeditor.com), it works like a charm on Opera and is also very configurable and powerful. I also had some issues with TinyMCE using the latest Opera to date (v12.15).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of Opera Mini you are using. The supported version is  v.50 and above. The Opera Mini version 52.3.21517  and above are the supported version for TinyMCE. You can get the version 50 of  opera mini mobile browser here https://press.opera.com/2019/02/19/opera-for-android-hits-version-50/